# How to run latest docker and docker-compose development versions?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.10

I'm trying to figure out how to run development builds of docker and docker-compose together on Ubuntu 14.10 to hopefully address a bug: https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1349

Latest Docker development version

```
docker -v
# Docker version 1.7.0-dev, build 6a7a757

# docker-compose -v
docker-compose version: 1.3.0rc3
CPython version: 2.7.8
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

But docker doesn't like the server version

```
# which docker 
/usr/bin/docker
# sudo /usr/bin/docker -d & 
WARN[0000] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit. 
INFO[0000] Loading containers: start.                   
.......................................................................INFO[0000] No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers : [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4] 
INFO[0000] No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers : [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4] 
WARN[0000] Failed to allocate and map port 8080: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use 

INFO[0000] Loading containers: done.                    
INFO[0000] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[0000] Docker daemon                                 commit=6a7a757 execdriver=native-0.2 graphdriver=aufs version=1.7.0-dev

# ps auxf | grep docker
root     24854  0.0  0.0  73360  3800 pts/14   S    09:59   0:00          |       \_ sudo /usr/bin/docker -d
root     24866  0.0  0.1 439152 19556 pts/14   Sl   09:59   0:00          |       |   \_ /usr/bin/docker -d
root     24982  0.0  0.0 109264 14584 pts/14   Sl   09:59   0:00          |       |       \_ docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32768 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 29015
root     25102  0.0  0.1 109264 16552 pts/14   Sl   09:59   0:00          |       |       \_ docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32769 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 28015
root     25131  0.0  0.0 109264 14516 pts/14   Sl   09:59   0:00          |       |       \_ docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32770 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 8080

# docker ps
Error response from daemon: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.20, server: 1.15)
```

And the current development release candidate docker-compose expects server version 1.18

```
# which docker-compose 
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose
# docker-compose ps
client and server don't have same version (client : 1.18, server: 1.15)
```

Even after stopping the daemon, I still get the same error message

```
# sudo killall docker
INFO[0288] Processing signal 'terminated' 
# docker ps
Error response from daemon: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.20, server: 1.15)
```

I know I can downgrade the docker client to match version 1.18 which docker-compose requires, but I still don't understand why the server version is reporting as 1.15 when the same binary client appears to be 1.20.

Supplemental question: how is the docker client still receiving an incorrect server version message when the docker daemon is stopped?

Comment: You still have an old version of Docker running.

Comment: But it doesn't show up in ps, and there are no other docker binaries on the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this instance was that the environment variable `$DOCKER_HOST` was pointed to another system which was using a different version, hence no processes appearing in `ps` and incompatible APIs.

Removing the variable with `unset DOCKER_HOST` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the docker service after upgrading Docker (`sudo service docker restart`). That may be the cause of:

> You still have an old version of Docker running.

I had a very similar issue, ugraded Docker, and kept running into the same error message until I restarted the service.